# Why the shortcut created by my MSI install start the setup process again each time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I created my MSI installer for our C# application via VS 2008. I installed it. It created a shortcut for me on the desktop. I clicked that shortcut, the setup process running again and at the end our application was launched. It was not like this yesterday before I added some custom action to create database. I didn't recreate the shortcut in the installer. why it is like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSI comes with an auto-repair feature that checks whether all components installed by MSI are still present when you launch your application using the shortcut.

In your case, probably one (or more) components have been removed so the installer is launched again to repair your installation.

To prevent auto-repair from running either

- Make sure no file, registry setting or other installed component is removed

or

- Don't set the key path for those components. That will prevent MSI from checking those specific components

From your other questions it seems that your MSI has been created by a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project. Unfortunately, there is no option to modify the key path from within Visual Studio. You have the following options:

- Modify the MSI manually using Orca (This is not a good option because it is a manual step)
- Write a script e.g. using VBScript to patch the MSI file
- Move to a more advanced install system which gives you more control such as WiX or NSIS

Comment: you are right. I deleted some temp setup files (batch files and sql files). I need to find a way to avoid this. thanks

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: As your setup seems already quite complex you should definitely have a look at other ways than VS for creating your setup. Anyway, the VS setup projects will die in the future. If you are using VS 2010 you might also try InstallShield LE.

Comment: Sadly VS Setup Projects (VDPROJ) have no ability to control key files ( all resources including registry keys are a single key file to a single component ) and no way to disable advertised shortcuts. You have to be a pretty good MSI Jedi Master to know how to hack your way around the problem.  I suggest looking at InstallShield 2010LE or WiX.  VDPROJ died many years ago to me.

Answer (score 7):

Open the MSI manually using Orca. Add the following record to the Property table (Property, Value) without the quotes:

Property = 'DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS'
Value = '1'

This can also be scripted and run as part of a post build event.

Answer (score 1):

Is the shortcut pointing to your application or your setup?  If it's pointed to your setup and you change it to your application, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the system thinks the installation has been corrupted and is automatically attempting a repair,.Anything in the event logs (look for source of MsiInstaller in the Application Event log).

Have you been building multiple copies?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the application deletes a file that was deployed during the installation. The Auto-Repair is activated and hence you get the installation screen.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! I had an obsolete 'config.txt' file forgotten in the Setup, but this file is deleted and replaced by a 'config.xml' file when application launches. Removing file from Setup was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  In my case it turned out the issue was 'Manufacturer' and 'ProductName' fields inside Deoplyment Project properties.  It needs to be the same as the folder structure your shortcut is pointing to, otherwise you'll end up with the 'The resource 'C:\Program Files (x86)[Manufacturer][ProductName]\' does not exist' error inside Event Viewer.